# show database values in listbox when you open a form

Tags: vb.net

I'm just new to vb.net.. Anyway, Is there a way when I open my form the items in my database will show up automatically?

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            list()
        End Sub
        Sub list()
            con.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Tbl", con)
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            ListView1.Items.Clear()
            If rdr.HasRows Then
                Do While rdr.Read()
                    Dim arr As String() = New String(3) {}
                    Dim itm As ListViewItem
                    arr(0) = rdr("ID")
                    arr(1) = rdr("Name")
                    arr(2) = rdr("Brand")


                    itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
                    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
                Loop
            End If
            con.Close()
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Tbl")
        cmd.Connection = con
        Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            sda.Fill(dt)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using

Dim list As List(Of DataRow) = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList()
```

this code can convert direct data table to list.